# SQL: where clause with priority

Tags: sql

I want to write a select query with where clause having two conditions.

```
select distinct user_name from table1 where column1 = 'AAAA' or is null
```

I want to give priority to AAAA if records with both AAAA and null are found.
How to do that?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `ORDER BY`?

Comment: NO.   Suppose i have 2 records which have same user_name, but have 2 values(AAAA , NULL) for column1 attribute. Then I want only record with AAAA to be shown

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. As formatted text, not images.

Comment: If both records have the exact same outcome. Why should one prioritize the other?

Comment: As you are only showing the `user_name` there is no way you could distinguish those two rows in the result as the user_name is the same for both.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the 'null' entries only if the corresponding AAAA does not exist :

WHERE ... OR (column1 is null AND not exists (select * from table1 as inner where inner.user_name = outer.user_name and inner.column1 = 'AAAA'))

The variation using EXCEPT would be closer to RA-style thinking but would probably fail precisely because you're working with NULL here.

EDIT

(And this answer is only to be kept in mind for the cases where you need more attributes from the row than just the user_name and those attributes must match precisely the row retained for the result set.)

Comment: seems good....can you please write the exact query for the same...what is outer ?

Comment: No sorry not going to do that.  I have a rather strict policy of not spoonfeeding complete results.  'outer' is the alias name you'll have to introduce for table1 in your outermost select (the one you currently have already) e.g. SELECT ... FROM table1 as outer WHERE ...

Answer (score 0):

It's just

```
select distinct user_name from table1 where column1 = 'AAAA' or column1 is null
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "if records with both AAAA and null are found." give priority to AAAA"?

One interpretation is to return AAAA records.  If none exist, then choose `NULL`:

```
select distinct user_name
from table1
where column1 = AAAA
union all
select distinct user_name
from table1
where column1 is null and (not exists select 1 from table1 where column1 = AAAA);
```

Comment: that select after union all risks ending up pretty empty ... (methinks)

Comment: @ErwinSmout . . . Only if there are AAAA values.  If there are no AAAA values, then it will produce the result set for the overall query.

Comment: I don't write SQL every day.  But it seems to me that one single AAAA value will eradicate *all* user names from that second part of the union, regardless of the user_name that appears in the AAAA row at hand.

Comment: @ErwinSmout . . . That is correct.  That is how I interpret the question.

Comment: Fair enough.  The question indeed leaves enough room for that interpretation.  But it doesn't line up with OP's first comment under the question itself.